# How do I change/recover my password?

Tags: ssh, password

I have made several personal configuration changes to a Raspbian Wheezy install (more secure ssh, personal configurations, etc). It's been a couple weeks since I last touched it, and I completely forgot the password to login. What should I do?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Right off the bat, let me say that there is not a way to *recover* a password (without some actual cracking/hacking which I don't know how to do). Resetting your password is your best bet.

So the first step will be to determine if you have any way to log in to the Raspbery Pi.

If you're able to log in with a user that has 'sudo' rights (this includes SSH... perhaps you have keys set up properly but forgot the actual user password, which I ran in to), simply typing:

```
sudo passwd
```

should prompt you to create a new password (without having to enter your current password).

Another option would be to run the starting config and change the password that way.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

If you're completely locked out, you can [try the technique mentioned here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3//viewtopic.php?f=47&t=20397), though I didn't have any success with the strategy. It just kept me from finishing booting up the RPi.

I haven't found any good techniques to enable root access period (putting the conversation of why you'd even want to do that aside :) ), let alone if you can't log in. Somebody can correct me if I'm wrong.

Hopefully this will save you from blowing away an image with a fresh one. If this saves one person, figure it's worth the time to post :)

Comment: Strangely 'sudo pwd' did not work for me (additional permissions needed?), but interactive sudo 'sudo -i' session and then just pwd did work. So thanks for help

Comment: @user14087 It should be `passwd`, not `pwd`. Updated answer to show this.

Comment: *"without some actual cracking/hacking"* -- In fact there's no way to do that either beyond random guessing (aka. brute force); passwords are not stored on the system.   Only a [one-way hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of them is (emphasis on **one-way**).

Comment: The questioner probably wants to reset the password for the account "pi". If you have forgotten that password, but have SSH key access, logon and use this command:    `sudo passwd pi`  If you omit the "pi", you will be changing the password for the root account.

Answer (score 23):

Mount the SD card, go into the file system, and edit `/etc/passwd`. Find the line starting with "pi" that begins like this:

```
pi:x:1000:1000...
```

Get rid of the x; leave the colons on either side. This will eliminate the need for a password.

You probably then want to create a new password by using the `passwd` command after you log in.

Comment: this method worked very well, thank you - changing the encrypted password to `*` didn't work, and the adding a `init=/bin/sh` method was useless... +1

Comment: I can not say if this method worked in the passed but it certainly does not work now.

Comment: This worked for me. RPi3B+ Raspbian 9.4 (stretch)

Comment: This didn't work for me.  However, a simple solution was just to add my client's public ssh key into the mounted pi's sd card's /home/pi/.ssh/authorized_keys.  Then it is possible to ssh in and run passwd as normal

Comment: @UsAaR33 Your comment is so far the best answer in the context of headless pi. Thanks a lot! You should add it as a separate answer! :)

Answer (score 14):

If you have physical access to the pi, look at [these instructions.](http://rpi.tnet.com/project/faqs/resetpasswd) Essentially, mount the SD card using a different machine and edit `cmdline.txt` to include (at the end) `init=/bin/sh`. Then, run the following commands:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd pi
(enter a new password)
sync
exec /sbin/init
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using Raspbmc and this was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: If you get an error running the mount command, run this instead: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/mmcblk0p2 /`

Answer (score 9):

As Jamie Cox commented in one answer and what actually worked for my problem, you might want to change the password for the pi user, so type

```
sudo passwd pi
```

otherwise you are just changing the password for root.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have physical access to your SD.

Create new password: `openssl passwd -6 -salt salt hello-world`

You will receive something like: `$6$salt$phlWRlSMVXZ1JJxGL/j5ANI.m8sbGpNT5pQE8iyx2TxYPKIZZhPM.eMN0axmoRHY3CrZU2KeyhTOcjBkKeD.N/`

Edit `/etc/shadow` on your Pi's SD's root partition and replace the encrypted password with newly generated or edit `/etc/rc.local` and say "`echo 'pi:password' | chpasswd`" or "`echo 'pi:<generated-password>' | chpasswd -e`"

Comment: I had no HDMI adapter for the RasPi 4, so the above answers did not help (I'm sure they work, but they require being connected directly to the Pi, they do not work over SSH). I ran Linux Mint in a VM and followed your steps, it was straight to the point. Thanks.