# Forgot my password

Tags: password

I set up the cups interface so I could print to my wireless printer.

Some where in all the confusion i must have changed my password.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried any methods from http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/how-do-i-change-recover-my-password?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the CUPS web interface always required the **root** user password. You probably need to actually set the root password to be able to use it (`sudo -i` to become root user, then `passwd` to set the root user password).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the password from the Pi, by removing the SD card and mounting on some other system and follow the guide Below.

[For making Your Rpi auto login](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html)