# Rpi not Accepting default password when connected via ssh

Tags: ssh, headless

I was trying to setup a ssh connection to my pi 2 (model B, i.e., no inbuilt wifi) in headless mode from my ubuntu machine. I do not have a router. After multiple attempts of flashing and tweaking, the following worked,

1. Add ssh file in /boot
2. Uncommenting the following lines in /etc/dhcpcd.conf

> ```
> profile static_eth0
> static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
> static routers=192.168.1.1
> static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1
>
> interface eth0
> fallback static_eth0
> ```

After this it asks for

> pi@192.168.1.23's password:

to which i supplied the default password for rpi

> raspberry

but it keeps saying  Permission denied, please try again.for three times after which it closes the connection. I tried [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/12676/97305) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/76961/97305), but it would not work. Note that I do not have a windows machine or a hdmi-in enabled screen. I don't remember having this problem in earlier versions of raspbian. I am using 2018-11-13-raspbian-stretch-full.img.

Comment: @Milliways I connected my rpi to my laptop via an ethernet cable after adding the empty ssh file in /boot/. However, I was not able to establish a ssh connection via the command `$ssh pi@raspberrypi` as it would say `Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi: Name or service not known`. After making a static IP in /etc/dhcpcd.conf I was able to connect but now I think I am not getting access to the default user, hence it's not accepting the default password.

Comment: You do not put `ssh` in `/boot` but into the boot partition. You should use `raspberrypi.local` in most OS. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: @Milliways sorry, my bad. I put ssh into the boot partition only after flashing the image file. And I tried both `$ssh pi@raspberrypi` and `$ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`. Since this problem did not occur before when I used this with windows + putty, I assumed it has something to do with the DHCP connection on my laptop hence I gave it a static IP. I dont know much about DHCP hence I avoid it :p

Comment: try running `ssh -vvv` as this will give more verbose output which help work out why permission is denied.  You can disable passwords in sshd_config.

Comment: @Milliways I reflashed the os added the file and restarted my computer. It worked with `$ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` and it started working fine with it. I think the problem was with my ubuntu machine dhcp earlier. Thanks!

Comment: Does the `ssh` file get deleted from the first partition? I think I'm right in saying that after the SSH service has been started it should delete the file: the `ssh` file is a one-time option and is not persistent. I also see to remember reading somewhere recently that it only works on a fresh install as well, try re-writing the card and add your `ssh` and `wpa-supplicant.conf` to it before booting.

Comment: Please make your comment that it worked now an answer. This will finish your question and show other users that it has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I did,

> $ssh pi@192.168.1.23

after making my IP static, pi gave the following,

> pi@192.168.1.23's password:

Which was misleading, as no user 192.168.1.23 exists. Hence it kept showing Permission Denied. It would ask passwords for this user, even when I had disabled passwords.

Finally, after restarting my computer and re-flashing the OS on the SD card, I was able to get it working without static IP. And the standard command worked,

> $ssh pi@raspberrypi.local

I figured that DHCP must have been misbehaving on my computer as I kept switching my ethernet port from RPI to LAN. After restarting it must have got reset.

Comment: "as no user 192.168.1.23 exists" – 192.168.1.23 is the host, not the user.

Answer (score 0):

No more default `pi` user with `raspberry` password.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/

Comment: True, but this doesn't answer the question of a problem in 2019.  This is more of a comment.

Comment: I had this kind of problem and I'd like to find this kind of answer here, as the search engine suggests this page.